# What might be the issue with my pipeline to rendering the depth buffer to a texture?

Tags: c++, opengl, depth, zbuffer, depth-testing

The main steps for depth testing from my understanding:
1) enable depth testing and how we want to depth test
2) create the frame buffer object and make sure it has a depth attached to it
3) bind our frame buffer object ( make sure to clear it before rendering )
4) draw stuff

And that should be it no? our frame buffer depth attachment should have depth data? But I always get straight 1's default depth clear color

step 1:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc( GL_LEQUAL );
```

step 2:

```
//create the frame buffer object
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_uifboHandle);

// Initialize FBO
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_uifboHandle);

//create 2 texture handles 1 for diffuse, 1 for depth
unsigned int m_uiTextureHandle[2];
glGenTextures( 2, m_uiTextureHandle );

//create the diffuse texture
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_uiTextureHandle[0]);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, uiWidth, uiHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_uiTextureHandle[0], 0);
```

.

```
//create the depth buffer
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_uiTextureHandle[1]);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP );

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, uiWidth, uiHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_uiTextureHandle[1], 0);

//go back to default binding
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

step 3:

```
//bind the frame buffer object
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_uifboHandle );

//clear it
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
```

step 4:

```
//draw things
```

Are these not the steps?
Am i missing something?
I've tried a few different tutorials.
I can't get any depth to render to a texture
I keep getting straight 1's over and over.

Comment: Try to add filtering parameters after binding your depth texture, just like you did after binding your diffuse texture.

Comment: added it. still nothing

Answer (score 0):

The framebuffer probably is not complete. Try [checking for completeness](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Completeness). Moreover your code was:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, uiWidth, uiHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

However, it should be (watch the RGB-RGBA):

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, uiWidth, uiHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```